# How to effectively append elements with js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok i edited the question to be more "focused".

So i am making a list with divs with js that append multiple times to the parent with every click of its corresponding button.
Im having trouble interacting with the created divs,i made an onclick function which appends a new `<input>` to the bottom of its div,and this function listens only to the very first element i create but not for every one of them,and for some reason it appends the inputs to the last one.
Any ideas where to look ?

```js
var countBlue = 0;
var countRed = 0;
var countGreen = 0;


function addBlue (){
var addTo = document.getElementById('div1')
var blue = document.createElement("div");


blue.id="blueDiv";
blue.innerHTML = "<input id=blueInput><button id=innerButtonBlue>ADD INPUTS</button>";
addTo.appendChild(blue);

    
document.getElementById("innerButtonBlue").onclick = function(){
    
    var newInput = document.createElement("div");
    newInput.innerHTML = '<input id="newInput" placeholder="NEW">';
    blue.appendChild(newInput);
}

    
    

countBlue++;
    

}

function addRed (){
var addTo = document.getElementById('div1')
var red = document.createElement("div");

red.id="redDiv";
red.innerHTML = "<input id=redInput><button id=innerButtonRed>ADD INPUTS</button>";
addTo.appendChild(red);
    
document.getElementById("innerButtonRed").onclick = function(){
    
    var newInput = document.createElement("div");
    newInput.innerHTML = '<input id="newInput" placeholder="NEW">';
    red.appendChild(newInput);
}
    
countRed++;
    
}



function addGreen (){
var addTo = document.getElementById('div1')
var green = document.createElement("div");

green.id="greenDiv";
green.innerHTML = "<input id=greenInput><button id=innerButtonGreen>ADD INPUTS</button>";
addTo.appendChild(green)
    
document.getElementById("innerButtonGreen").onclick = function(){
    
    var newInput = document.createElement("div");
    newInput.innerHTML = '<input id="newInput" placeholder="NEW">';
    green.appendChild(newInput);
}
countGreen++;
} 
function displayCounters(){
alert("Blue divs amount : " + parseInt(countBlue) + "\n" + " Red divs amount : " + parseInt(countRed) + "\n" + " Green divs amount : " + parseInt(countGreen) + "\n" + "\n" + " All together is : " + (parseInt(countBlue) + parseInt(countRed) + parseInt(countGreen)) )    
}
```

```css
button{
  margin-bottom:10px;
}


#blueDiv{
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  width:270px;
  
 
  
}
#redDiv{
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  width:270px;
 
  }
#greenDiv{
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  width:270px;
  
  }

input{
  text-align:center;
  
}
#innerButtonRed{
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    
}
#innerButtonBlue{
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    
}
#innerButtonGreen{
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    
}
#newInput{
margin-top: 2px;
width:162px;
height:23px;
    
}
#redInput{
    background: red;
}
#blueInput{
    background: blue;
}
#greenInput{
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<script src ="test.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
<button onclick="addBlue()">BLUE</button>
<button onclick="addRed()">RED</button>
<button onclick="addGreen()">GREEN</button>
<button onclick="displayCounters()">COUNTERS</button>
<div id="div1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you willing to use jQuery?

Comment: sure,it will be a start for learning it

Answer (score 0):

Your input is only being added once per color because you're only calling document.createElement to create an input element once per color. You should call document.createElement in the onclick callback function every time you need to add a new one:

```
document.getElementById("innerButtonBlue").onclick = function(){
    alert("New Input Added");
    var newInput = document.createElement("div");
    newInput.innerHTML = '<input id="newInput" placeholder="NEW">';
    blue.appendChild(newInput);
}
```

Adding new inputs isn't moving the ones below them down because the inputs are contained within a div that has its height set to 10px; this means that everything within the div will be constrained to this height and won't be able to push other items down.

Also, every time you call document.getElementById to obtain an innerButton and attach an event listener to it, you are obtaining the very first innerButton with that color and attaching the event listener to that; you could fix that by setting `blue.getElementById("innerButtonBlue").onclick` so that you're attaching the event listener to the button that you've just created:

```
blue.getElementById("innerButtonBlue").onclick = function(){
    alert("New Input Added");
    var newInput = document.createElement("div");
    newInput.innerHTML = '<input id="newInput" placeholder="NEW">';
    blue.appendChild(newInput);
}
```

and so on for the other colors.

Comment: sorry i did'nt quite understand the last part of your comment,i'm doing it the way you tell me but makes the code stop working,probably i dont implement it correctly.
Could you clarify how would i do that ?
i still cant get the function to listen to every button,and it keeps sending my appends to the last one of its kind !

Answer (score 0):

the way to do that.

```js
const elements =
        { Blue  : { count: 0, lib: 'This is the blue div' }
        , Red   : { count: 0, lib: 'This is the red div' }
        , Green : { count: 0, lib: 'This is the Green div' }
        }
  ,   topButtons = document.getElementById('grpButtons')
  ,   containerD = document.getElementById('container')
  ;
topButtons.onclick = e => // event delegation 
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('button')) return  // ignore click outside any button

  let cls = e.target.dataset.class
  
  if (cls==='')
    { 
    alert(`
Blue divs amount..: ${elements.Blue.count}
Red divs amount...: ${elements.Red.count}
Green divs amount.: ${elements.Green.count}\n
All together is : ${elements.Blue.count + elements.Red.count + elements.Green.count} `)  
    }
  else
    {
    ++elements[cls].count
    let nD = document.createElement('div')
      , lb = document.createElement('label')
      , nI = document.createElement('input')
      , bt = document.createElement('button')
      ;
    nD.className   = cls
    lb.textContent = elements[cls].lib
    nI.placeholder = 'new'
    bt.textContent = 'Add input'
    bt.dataset.cod = 'Add'

    nD.appendChild(lb)
    nD.appendChild(nI)
    nD.appendChild(bt)
    containerD.appendChild(nD)
    }
  }
containerD.onclick = e =>
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('button')) return  // ignore click outside any button

  let parentD = e.target.closest('div')
    , nI      = document.createElement('input')
    ;
  ++elements[parentD.className].count
  nI.placeholder = 'new'
  parentD.appendChild(nI)
  }
```

```css
#grpButtons { margin-bottom: 1.4em; }
#grpButtons button { width : 8em; }
#grpButtons button:last-of-type { width : 16em }

#container {
  margin-top : 1em;
  width      : 24em;
  display    : block;
  }
#container > div {
  width    : calc(100% - .6em);
  margin   : 1em .3em;
  overflow : auto;
  }
#container > div label {
  display             : inline-block;
  width               : 100%;
  border-bottom       : 7px;
  border-bottom-style : solid;
  text-align          : center;
  text-transform      : uppercase;
  }
#container > div.Blue  label { color: blue;  border-bottom-color: blue;  }
#container > div.Red   label { color: red;   border-bottom-color: red;   }
#container > div.Green label { color: green; border-bottom-color: green; }

#container > div > input,
#container > div > button { 
  margin : .3em;
  }
#container > div > input {
  float : left;
  clear : both;
  }
#container > div > button {
  float : right;
  }
```

```html
<div id="grpButtons">
  <button data-class="Blue"  > BLUE  </button>
  <button data-class="Red"   > RED   </button>
  <button data-class="Green" > GREEN </button>
  <button data-class=""   > COUNTERS </button>
</div>

<div id="container">
</div>
```